# Deconvolution of signal with harmonic distortion

Tags: deconvolution, distortion

I came across these measurements done using a stepped sine sweep covering only some frequencies (~800 frequency points).
I would like to get an impulse response from these measurements to convolve them with another signal. I have the input signal x and the output y. To obtain the frequency response, I perform a deconvolution.

Besides having few frequency points, the problem is that there is some harmonic distortion as well as some electrical noise. Any input in how to get the best out of these measurements?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: do you know the absolute phase of each sine step? Otherwise, you only have amplitude, but no phase information, and that's half of the information necessary to construct an impulse response. The fact that there's nonlinearity only makes matters more complicated, and means you will not be able to reconstruct thing unambigously (unless you have more information about the impulse response you forget to mention!)